# Control is not getting focused on Keyup event

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi all I have created a dynamic combo box with a Textbox and a button to appear as dropdown style, every thing works fine but I handled `keyup` event for the textbox so that when user enter some text I will search for the results and display them

```
 private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     //Some code to filter my data 
     textBox1.Focus();
 }
```

But I am unable to set the focus Immediately back to the textbox after results getting displayed so can some one help me

Code I used is from here

http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/showcode.asp?txtCodeId=8554&lngWid=10

Comment: Can you show us the code for the 'dynamic combo box' ? (above sample is not very helpful in figuring out what the problem is)

Comment: Have you tried debugging (set break point at `textBox1.Focus()`)?

Comment: How are you displaying the results exactly?

Comment: where does the result displayed? Is it possible that the focus is on that control where it is displayed? And if yes then probably when the result is displayed that's the time that you do the textBox1.Focus()

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the `Focus()` method is a bit flaky.

Other options:

```
textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length - button1, 1);
```

...or simply:

```
textBox1.Select();
```

If you can verify that something else is going wrong, then this might be off base, otherwise you might simply be fighting weirdness.